# @bigcommerce/stencil-cli | Error on Node v10.6.0

Tags: node.js, bigcommerce, node-sass

#### Expected behavior

I tried to do `npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli`, but this turns out to be a long error message (see below)

#### Actual behavior

```
gyp verb command build []
gyp verb build type Release
gyp verb architecture x64
gyp verb node dev dir /Users/albert/.node-gyp/10.6.0
gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/albert/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node -I/Users/albert/.node-gyp/10.6.0/src -I/Users/albert/.node-gyp/10.6.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/albert/.node-gyp/10.6.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/albert/.node-gyp/10.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/albert/.node-gyp/10.6.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/albert/.node-gyp/10.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../../../nan  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++1y -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o ../src/binding.cpp
In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:3:
../src/sass_context_wrapper.h:8:10: fatal error: 'sass/context.h' file not found
#include <sass/context.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.6.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/@bigcommerce/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@6.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-react@^4.2.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @bigcommerce/node-sass@3.4.4 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @bigcommerce/node-sass@3.4.4 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/albert/.npm/_logs/2018-10-22T07_02_07_953Z-debug.log
```

#### Steps to reproduce behavior

Mac OSX High Sierra
Node v10.6.0
NPM 6.4.1

Comment: Hi, Node has only been tested up to 8.12.0. Can you please retry with that version of Node. https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/prerequisites-mac-os

Comment: Hey T.J, thanks for your suggestion. I end up downgrading my Node version to match stencil's specs. Just wondering why stencil hasn't been supporting Node v10 since it is supported by big guy like BigCommerce, I am expecting that at the very least.

Comment: Node-sass 3.4.4 is an unofficial fork that they&#39;re running themselves. Node 10 usually requires node-sass 4.9.x

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue and solved it by downgrading to Node v7.9.0, as per [the specs on this page in the Stencil docs.](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/getting-started/installing-stencil#installing_prerequisites)

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this works:

1. Uninstall the original version of node

   brew uninstall node
2. Install node version 8

brew install "node@8"

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

node install